# как кликнуть на все элементы через js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Добрый день допустим у меня вот такой код есть

```js
$(".Checkbox").click();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="ListItem-button" role="button" tabindex="0">
   <label class="Checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox">
</div>
<div class="ListItem-button" role="button" tabindex="0">
   <label class="Checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox">
</div>
<div class="ListItem-button" role="button" tabindex="0">
   <label class="Checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox">
</div>
```

Мне нужно оттуда через js взять label и кликнуть по нему чтоб была галочка

Он кликает, но не на все label

Как сделать чтоб он в каждом label у которого класс .Checkbox галочку  поставил?

Comment: По каждому элементу пройтись через цикл и кликнуть не пробовал?

Comment: @ГорМанучарян пробовал ну он только на одном элементе ставит галочку и убирает(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я лишь добавил названия к `label`, но это ни на что не влияет, основное - это правильный селектор. Я просто выбрал все элементы, у которых `type` равно `checkbox` и вызвал событие `click` на всех них:

```js
$("[type=checkbox]").click();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="ListItem-button" role="button" tabindex="0">
  <label class="Checkbox">Label 1</label>
  <input type="checkbox">
</div>
<div class="ListItem-button" role="button" tabindex="0">
  <label class="Checkbox">Label 2</label>
  <input type="checkbox">
</div>
<div class="ListItem-button" role="button" tabindex="0">
  <label class="Checkbox">Label 3</label>
  <input type="checkbox">
</div>
```

Если принципиально именно к классу `label` привязываться, то можете использовать

```js
$(".Checkbox + input").click();
```

вместо того что в примере. Такой селектор просто берёт последующий соседний элемент `input` от элемента с классом `Checkbox`.

Если на странице несколько элементов с классом `Checkbox`, не являющихся `label`, то можете конкретизировать таким образом:

```js
$("label.Checkbox + input").click();
```

Но если и `input`-ов может быть несколько типов после `label`-а с классом `Checkbox`, то вот последний вариант, который я могу предложить:

```js
$("label.Checkbox + input[type=checkbox]").click();
```

Comment: А если html не изменять ? Смотрите мне по факту нужно именно на странице в консоли написать этот код ,понимаю дебильно звучит ,ну все же может друго способ есть?

Comment: @VindettaGinachi Так подойдёт?

Comment: Спасибо большое )

Comment: @VindettaGinachi Обращайтесь! Также добавил ещё один вариант на всякий случай :)